# Triggering parent component's useEffect before child component's useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am currently implementing metrics/analytics in a React application and I am trying to log pages in the order they are opened [(related)](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15281). I have a certain page e.g ParentComponent and I have embedded there-in, child component e.g ChildComponent.

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
   // log page using useEffect
   return (<ChildComponent />)
}

const ChildComponent = () => {
   // log page using useEffect
   // return something else 
}
```

Both components have useEffects e.g

```
useEffect(() => {
   // log page e.g ParentComponent or ChildComponent.
}, []);
```

However, I notice every-time that the child's useEffect is called before the parent's. My understanding is that this is understandable as the child is rendered fully before the parent is. But I please need to know if there are any ways of ensuring I can call functionality in the parent's first of all before calling functionality in the child's?

Thanks.

Comment: This is how react lifecycle and effects work. Perhaps instead pass a callback from the parent page to its children pages that they call when they mount, then let the parent page organize/structure how it wants to log that it and all its child pages mounted.

Comment: If they are different pages (that need exclusive logging), why are they related as parent-child? Couldn't you make them as siblings? The behavior your are intending with `useEffect` is not possible.

Comment: @cbdeveloper, nice point actually but in this parent component, there is a grid switcher which has tab buttons that triggers loading certain components. I need to pass both the parent component and the child component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior your are intending with `useEffect` is not possible. Here is a possible workaround:

```js
function App() {
  return(
    <ParentPage/>
  );
}

function ParentPage() {

  const logParent = React.useCallback(() => {
    console.log("Logging ParentPage...");
  },[]);
  
  return(
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>I am ParentPage...</div>
      <ChildPage
        logParent={logParent}
      />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

function ChildPage(props) {

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (props.logParent) {
      props.logParent();
    }
    console.log("Logging ChildPage...");
  },[]);

  return(
    <div>I am ChildPage...</div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I am currently facing this issue right now. My solution is to use `useLayoutEffect` on the parent component instead of using `useEffect`:

```
import React, { useEffect, useLayoutEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function Parent({ children }) {
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    console.log("Parent first render");
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>parent</h2>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
}

function Child() {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Child will render after");
  });

  return <h3>child</h3>;
}

function App() {
  return (
    <Parent>
      <Child />
    </Parent>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run the parent effect before the child effect, you can use the `Effect Component`, and place it before the child compoent.

```
export function Effect({ effect }) {
  useEffect(() => effect?.(), [effect])
  return null
}

function Parent() {
  const stableEffect = useCallback(() => doStuff(), [])

  return (
    <>
      <Effect effect={stableEffect}></Effect>
      <Child />
    </>
  )
}
```